# CLOSED - Just install git but the console don't recognise the git commands

Tags: git, bash, console, osx-snow-leopard

I'm new here and I want to know how to use Bitbucket so I followed [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=269981802).

At the 7th instruction, after successfully installing Git as they said I have on the console

```
host:~ Me$ git --version
-bash: git: command not found
```

I have the file `git-1.8.5.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg` in my `Downloads`.

What should I do to have `git` recognized by the console?

I have been told to do `echo "PATH=$PATH/Downloads" >> .bashrc`
or to use a Source tree.

The first one didn't work and I don't see the utility or using a Source Tree.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a directory to your `$PATH` usually doesn't take effect until you log out and log in again (or at the very least restart your terminal). Try that, and then see if you can run `git --version`.

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is a free graphical Git / Mercurial client from Atlassian for Windows and OSX. You may want to try that out instead of (or in addition to) the command-line interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I do that it says Segmentation fault: 11 , what does it means?

Comment: Just saw what it means but I don't know what to do with it

Comment: @Arcay, it means that `git` tried to access memory it shouldn't have. There's not generally much you can do about it unless you want to debug the source code. Perhaps try installing [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) as the article suggests? It does provide a command-line interface to Git as well as a GUI. Frankly, it's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
/usr/local/bin/git  --version
```

Seems the PATH "/usr/local/bin" is not in your default path, you can edit your local profile ~/.profile and add below line in it to fix this issue.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I have no such file or directory when I do /usr/local/bin/git  --version

Comment: Thank you for your answer, before seeing your comment I did that : 
host:~ Me$ git
Segmentation fault: 11
host:~ Me$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
host:~ Me$ git
Segmentation fault: 11
host:~ Me$ which git
Segmentation fault: 11

I don't know what it means I'm going to search, maybe it's because I installed 2 different versions of git

Comment: I'm sorry when I do Add comment it doesn't go inline, even when I put > at the beginning of the sentences

Comment: Sorry it's a mess I will correct and gives a proper comment in no time but I have to go for the moment, it case you see this before.